Focal length and clip end constantly reset
I am having a problem (only recently) where my focal length and clip end settings randomly reset to their default values in edit mode. I'll change them, and then after a few operations they'll be back to their previous values.
It might not be such an issue if I could change the default values, but I also can't seem to find where the defaults are set - they don't appear to stick in the startup file.
edit: here it is after it resets


Hello, could you please include screenshots of your workspace in your post?

Yes, please show at least one screenshot of your camera settings for example... otherwise we can only start asking you for each possible setting here. By the way, I'm not sure what you mean by "resetcm to their default values in edit mode": I thought you were talking about the camera, but there is no Edit Mode for camera objects...

Hi, and thanks! It's not actually a camera setting, it's for the viewport. And TBH, the only reason I'm adjusting those settings is because my edges are clipping through planes, even without x-ray.  Adjusting the clip depth seems to fix it, but it won't stick. Maybe I should have led with that..
